# Search a column of text by adjecent cell and return a binary value (excel)

Tags: excel

What's a good way to search a column of text (e.g. A1:A10) by adjecent cell (e.g. B1) and return a binary value (e.g. 0 or 1) in the next column (e.g. C1:C10)?

my 'un-elegant' approach so far: use VLOOKUP, then filter and delete all fields that return an error.

[image]

Comment: please explain downvotes to help improve questions in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple MATCH will do for you

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&B1&"*",A1:A10,0)),1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly you are wanting column C to show 1 or 0 depending on whether text in column B appears in text in column A, if so:

```
formula in C2 to extend down =if(find(B2, A2) > 0, 1, 0)
```

FIND will return the location of the first occurrence of the first argument within the second

EDIT

Ok, if you want to check all of column A use this:

```
=OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(B1, A1:A8))))
```

Again its array formula so complete with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

So its doing a FIND for B1 against all of column A, any row that doesn't contain B1 is going to return an error. So now you have an array whose values are either ERROR or a number indicating B1 is found, you can then use the ISERROR function on each element of the array and then NOT each element, you will then have a TRUE for each row B1 appears in, then collapse it all to a single value using OR :) you can extend this formula in B1 down for the other rows but make sure to lock A1:A8 as in $A$1:$A$8

Comment: Almost - I want to find B2 within a *whole column* of A (e.g. A1:A10). That somehow throws an error for me when I use find